# Excel macro: Modifying formula and appending segment

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

In an Excel worksheet, I would like to modify several formulas by deleting the last character and adding an additional criterion to it.

Basically, instead of:

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A10, B1:B10, "", C1:C10, "Test")
```

I would like to have:

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A10, B1:B10, "", C1:C10, "Test", C1:D10, "Test2")
```

Given my general lack of knowledge on VBA, I can't seem to figure it out... The following produces an error:

```
Sub AppendCriterion()
    Dim a As String
    a = Right(Selection.Formula, Len(Selection.Formula) - 1)
    a = Selection.Formula + ", C1:D10, "Test2")"
    Selection.Formula = a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll step through this for you, but in the future I recommend utilizing Debug.Print and F8 (step into) to troubleshoot your code.

#### Line 3:

```
a = Right(Selection.Formula, Len(Selection.Formula) - 1)
```

This is actually going to subtract 1 character from the left side.

```
Input: =SUMIFS(A1:A10, B1:B10, "", C1:C10, "Test")
Output: SUMIFS(A1:A10, B1:B10, "", C1:C10, "Test")
```

So, change `Right(..)` to `Left(...)`

```
Input: =SUMIFS(A1:A10, B1:B10, "", C1:C10, "Test")
Output: =SUMIFS(A1:A10, B1:B10, "", C1:C10, "Test"
```

Now that we have the ) removed, let's move on to Line 4 where you are appending the new criterion.

#### Line 4

```
a = Selection.Formula + ", C1:D10, "Test2")"
```

Some notes about this, if you want to display a quotation character in a string, you have to escape it with quotations and it gets a little confusing. Also, you're setting `a = Selection.Formula` + .. which is the original, and not the string you modified on line 3. Lastly, your newly added criterion is C1:D10, which will cause a calculation error, I think you want D1:D10.

```
a = a + ", D1:D10, ""Test2"")"
```

#### Final Answer

```
Sub AppendCriterion()
    Dim a As String
    a = Left(Selection.Formula, Len(Selection.Formula) - 1)
    a = a + ", D1:D10, ""Test2"")"
    Selection.Formula = a
End Sub
```

Comment: @shkelda - it should also be noted that this will only work if `Selection` is a single cell.  As long as you are using this code one cell at a time, Adam's excellent answer will work.

Comment: This works wonderfully! Following @YowE3K's comment though, how would I go about for an operation across a range?

Comment: You'll have to clarify where your "SUM" field is in relation to your other "SUMIFS" sections, how many criterion you plan on adding for each SUMIFS statement etc.

Comment: Example: Your code is using A1:D10 at this point, where is your formula? (I put mine in A11 for testing)  If you added another section, what cells would it consume, and where would the formula be?